# How to calculate Euler integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have integral: $\int_0^{1} {\sqrt[n]{x-x^2}}$.

After some moves I'm getting next: $\int_0^{1} {\sqrt[n]{x-x^2}} = \int_0^{1} {x^{1/n}(1-x)^{1/n}} = B(\frac{n+1}{n};\frac{n+1}{n})$

But how to solve this finally?

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often called the [central Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBetaFunction.html). It is not elementary or easily evaluated exactly, even at rational values.

So this is "solved". For particular values of $n$, it's not hard to numerically approximate the integral to high precision.